# Python subprocess stderr/stdout field is None and returns returncode 1 if run a program in remote server

Tags: python, subprocess

When i am trying to run an unix script in remote server using python subprocess,it is failing and returning returncode 1 and stderr and stdout None

```
def runCCPAjob(self):
        out = []
        err = []
        session = FTP('#####.com','####','#####')
        session.cwd('/app/IIS/bin')
        print(session.pwd())
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "-x","/app/IIS/bin/E271_CCPA_ACCESS.ksh"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,encoding='utf-8',stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        rc = proc.wait()
        (stdoutdata, stderrdata) = proc.communicate()
        out.append(stdoutdata)
        err.append(stdoutdata)


        if proc.returncode == 0:
            return out
        else :
            raise Exception(proc.returncode,str(out),str(err),out,rc)           


p = sendFiletoServer()
p.runCCPAjob()
```

Error :
    raise Exception(proc.returncode,str(out),str(err),out,rc)
Exception: (1, "['']", "['']", [''], 1)

Comment: proc.stderr.read().decode() says sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n".